# sql query that select data that have only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying with this query to get only the rtp.releaseid that have a unique territory=200

```
select rtp.ReleaseId, rtp.TerritoryId  from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp where 
rtp.TerritoryId=200
```

but I guess something is missing , can you please help.
Thanks.

Comment: why do you think something is missing! This is absolutely ok.

Comment: Try: rtp.TerritoryId= '200'

Comment: Do you mean you want those `ReleaseId` that have a `TerritoryId = 200` and no other `TerritoryId <> 200`?

Comment: yes exactly I want ReleaseId that have a TerritoryId = 200 and no other TerritoryId <>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following with `NOT EXISTS` in a WHERE clause:

```
select rtp1.releaseId, rtp1.territoryId
from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp1
where rtp1.territoryId = 200
  and not exists (select releaseId
                  from ReleaseTerritoryPrice t2
                  where t2.territoryId <> 200
                    and rtp1.releaseId = t2.releaseId);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85ae6/2)

Or you can use `NOT IN` in a WHERE clause:

```
select rtp1.releaseId, rtp1.territoryId
from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp1
where rtp1.territoryId = 200
  and rtp1.releaseId not in (select releaseId
                              from ReleaseTerritoryPrice t2
                              where t2.territoryId <> 200);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85ae6/5)

Comment: I am trying to use the same logic in your query in order to have data that exist in territory 62 but not in territory 200 i did this but it doesn't work :      select distinct r.UPC,rtp1.releaseId, rtp1.territoryId
from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp1
inner join Release r on r.Id=rtp1.ReleaseId
where rtp1.territoryId = 62
  and not exists (select releaseId
                  from ReleaseTerritoryPrice t2
                  where t2.territoryId =200
                    and rtp1.releaseId = t2.releaseId);

Comment: @saadamiens try using the second one if I got the logic correct the following should work, see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d42e2/4  or even this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d42e2/6

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways

```
SELECT ReleaseId
FROM   ReleaseTerritoryPrice
WHERE  TerritoryId = 200 
EXCEPT
SELECT ReleaseId
FROM   ReleaseTerritoryPrice
WHERE  TerritoryId IS NULL OR TerritoryId <> 200
```

Or

```
SELECT ReleaseId
FROM   ReleaseTerritoryPrice
GROUP BY ReleaseId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TerritoryId) =1 AND MAX(TerritoryId )=200
```

Comment: I would like to use your first method with an inner join like this

Comment: inner join release r on r.id = release id , where can i put this line before or after the except ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this

```
SELECT MAIN.* FROM ReleaseTerritoryPrice MAIN
WHERE MAIN.ReleaseId in (
    SELECT rtp.ReleaseId
    FROM   ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp
    WHERE rtp.TerritoryId =200
    GROUP BY rtp.ReleaseId
    HAVING COUNT(rtp.TerritoryId) =1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword.

```
select DISTINCT rtp.ReleaseId, 
     rtp.TerritoryId  
from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp 
where rtp.TerritoryId=200
```